# CSS - rule works @media (max-width: 550px) but not @media (max-width: 750px)

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-float

```
.float-left-diva, .float-left-divb
```

This rule works (the divs will both stop floating and become 100% width) if it is placed in the @media max-width:550px but not at the @media max-width:750px.

I can't figure out why. I'm simply copying/pasting or highlighting and dragging it to move it, and making sure I'm not omitting the . or any of the ending. I've tried putting it above and below the .gallery class.  This is exactly how it is typed out in my style.css.

```
@media (max-width: 750px) {

.float-left-diva, .float-left-divb {
width:100%;
float:none;
margin:10px auto;
border:none;
}
.gallery {
width:48%;
margin:20px 1%;
float:left;
text-align:center;
}
}


@media (max-width: 550px) {

img.floatleft {
float:none; 
margin:10px auto
}
.homeboxes {
width:90%;
margin:20px 1%;
float: none;
text-align:center;
border:1px solid #A48A73;
}
#headerblock {
width:100%;
margin:0 auto;
}
.float-left-div, .float-left-div1, .float-left-div2 {
width:100%;
float:none;
margin:10px auto;
border:none;
}
}
```

Since it does work @550px I know I don't have a type O in my html compared to the css.  And I know everything else must be typed out right because it does what it is expected to do @550px.  I just want the divs to stop floating when the screen reaches max-width 750px. Div .float-left-diva has a little bit of text while .float-left-divb has an email form.  I also do not believe it is browser cache.  If I change it back to @550 it works again.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because the stylesheet cascades.

Try the highest pixel value at the bottom of the script.

Or add a min width to prevent the greater then 550 from overwriting things.